# if else statement for input arguments of a function in python

Tags: python, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I run my bash script `my_file.sh` in a python file as follows:

```
import subprocess

def rest_api():

    params = {
        'query': 'indepedence day',
        'formats': '["NEWSPAPER"]',
    }

    subprocess.call(['bash', 
                     'my_file.sh',
                     f'QUERY={params.get("query")}',
                     f'DOC_TYPE={params.get("formats")}',
                     f'LANGUAGE={params.get("lang")}', # returns None!
                    ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rest_api()
```

Several of my input arguments in `subprocess.call` do not normally exist in a dictionary `params={}` (here I provided `f'LANGUAGE={params.get("lang")}'` as one example). I handle such unavailability in `my_file.sh` to initialize with something, for instance:

```
if [ -z "$LANGUAGE" ]; then LANGUAGE="${LANGUAGE:-[]}"; fi
```

What I want is to apply some sort of `if else` statement in `subprocess.call` function with this logic:

if `params.get("lang")` is `None`, do not even send it as an input to bash file, e.g., treat it as I never provided such input for `my_file.sh`.

Therefore, I tried to rewrote my code like this:

```
subprocess.call(['bash', 
                         'my_file.sh',
                         f'QUERY={params.get("query")}',
                         f'DOC_TYPE={params.get("formats")}',
                         if params.get("lang"): f'LANGUAGE={params.get("lang")}', # syntax Error
                        ])
```

which is wrong I get the following `invalid syntax error`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nationalbiblioteket_logs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from url_scraping import *
  File "/home/xenial/WS_Farid/DARIAH-FI/url_scraping.py", line 17, in <module>
    from utils import *
  File "/home/xenial/WS_Farid/DARIAH-FI/utils.py", line 53
    if params.get("lang"): f'LANGUAGE={params.get("lang")}',
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Do I have a wrong understanding of applying `if else` statement for the input arguments of a  python function or is there an easier or cleaner way doing it?

Cheers,

Comment: `if` statements and conditional expressions are two entirely different things that share the same set of keywords. You can't have an conditional expression without the `else`, and you can't use an `if` statement inside another expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the default when calling `.get()`, so use an empty string.

```
f'LANGUAGE={params.get("lang", "")}'
```

Comment: This isn't what you asked for you in your question.

Comment: It solves the root problem, since the bash script handles empty values, but not `None`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the `LANGUAGE=` argument *at all* when no value is provided, you need to build the list dynamically.

```
    cmd = ['bash', 
           'my_file.sh',
           f'QUERY={params.get("query")}',
           f'DOC_TYPE={params.get("formats")}']
    if (lang := params.get("lang")) is not None:
        cmd += [f'LANGUAGE={lang}']
    
    subprocess.call(cmd)
```